# INSERT INTO error for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Hi this is my first time posting. I have searched all over for an answer but can't seem to find one that fixes mine. I am writing mysql code for a project and can't seem to insert data into a database I am creating. The link to the code is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be69b

Below is what I have come up with so far

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (`CustomerID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FirstName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`LastName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`Address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`Apt#` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
`City` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
`State` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`Zip` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
`HomePhone` VARCHAR(11),
`MobilePhone` VARCHAR(11),
`OtherPhone` VARCHAR(11), 
PRIMARY KEY(`CustomerID`)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES
(`1`, `John`, `Doe`, `123 Green St.`, `Apt A.`, `Richmond`, `VA`, `78646`, `18049481616`, ``, ``);
```

It throws out an error saying that `Unknown column 1 in field list`. I have tried doing this without `AUTO_INCREMENT` and it doesn't change anything. Can anyone help with this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't surrounding values in backticks making them string literals?

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1) You don't need to insert the `ID` since it's the field has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` clause.

2) You're using backticks which indicate column names, not strings.

```
INSERT INTO
    `customers`
    (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `Apt#`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`, `HomePhone`, `MobilePhone`, `OtherPhone`)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Doe', '123 Green St.', 'Apt A.', 'Richmond', 'VA', '78646', '18049481616', '', '');
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/392ddf

Comment: Thank you so much kchason! I completely missed the backticks. I crown myself idiot for the day lol. Changing this allowed the rows to be added successfully. I've programmed before but I'm completely new to databases. I should have seen this though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You define your table with "CustomerId" (`auto_increment`), so you shouldn't give a value for it in your insert-statement.

```
(1, John, Doe, 123 Green St., Apt A., Richmond, VA, 78646, 18049481616, ,)
```

should be

```
(John, Doe, 123 Green St., Apt A., Richmond, VA, 78646, 18049481616, ,)
```

That's what i think!

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I try and do when debugging sql code is to make sure that special characters and blanks aren't messing with the query.

Using your insert code above, I recreated your table, and this query worked:

```
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (null,'John', 'Doe', '123 Green St.', 'Apt A.', 'Richmond, VA', '78646', '18049481616', null,null, null)
```